# Automating Tomcat Thread/heap dump for further analysis

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm-arguments, jvisualvm, thread-dump

I am running an web application on tomcat. Tomcat process is getting hung when there are lots of requests fired. Since this is an production web app , i cant monitor all the time to get the tomcat java process/thread dump manually.

I have already enabled the jmx remote port on tomcat

`-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=2222
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true`

My question is : When the tomcat process hits high CPU[thread count]/Memory usage/got Hung , at that point of time can we collect the tomcat thread dump to desired disk location automatically[command line or programatically] ?

Comment: `jmx` with `ssl=false` on a production machine? Good work.

Comment: That is a sample args for opening jmx port which i specified.

Answer (score 0):

These options:

`JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/path/to/dir'`

will make a core dump when Tomcat runs out of memory.

Also `-verbose:gc` option might be useful in this case.

> **B.2.3 -verbose:gc Option**
>
> The `-verbose:gc` option enables logging of garbage collection (GC)
>   information. It can be combined with other HotSpot VM specific options
>   such as `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` and `-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps` to get further
>   information about the GC. The information output includes the size of
>   the generations before and after each GC, total size of the heap, the
>   size of objects promoted, and the time taken.

[Troubleshooting Guide for HotSpot VM > Command-Line Options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/clopts.html)